# Tranform and Apply Expression via LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5

I am looking to support "expression passthru" as follows:

```
public IFastIndexingCollection<T> {
   // Main data structure here = 
   // Key = property name
   // Value = class below
   private Dictionary<string, ICustomCollection<T, U>> _indexedItems;

   public IEnumerable<T> FindWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
}

internal ICustomCollection<T, U> {
     // Main data structure =
     // T = type of data structure, e.g., Phone
     // U = property type, e.g., string
     // Key = value for given property (e.g., "Samsung")
     // Value = List<T> of items matching that key
     private ILookup<U, T> _backingLookup;
}
```

The trouble comes when we're trying to pass the LINQ expression through to the custom list. Say the user executes:

```
<T> = Phone
FastIndexingCollection<Phone>.FindWhere(x => x.Manufacturer.IndexOf("Samsung") > -1);
```

In this case, the code has to:

1. Figure out that the property in question is named "Manufacturer" and pull the relevant values(s) out of the dictionary for `key = "Manufacturer"`
2. Pass to, or otherwise transform, the expression so that the `ICustomCollection` dictionary value can actually recognize; `typeof(Manufacturer) = U = string`. So in my example of `x.Manufacturer.IndexOf(...)`, the "transformed" expression really doesn't need `x.Manufacturer` anymore because that's not stored in the lookup.
3. Execute a LINQ expression on the lookup that `ICustomCollection` is using

I've pulled the expression body off of the topmost expression to get the MethodInfo off of it, and can get to the right dictionary key value pair, but I can't figure out how to transform the LINQ expression so that so I can apply it on the "lowest" level `_backingLookup`: I tried to do something like:

```
foreach(var kvp in _backingLookup)
{
   if(...need to apply LINQ expression here... == true)
   {
        // Add _internalLookup[kvp.Key] to return value
   }
}
```

I just can't figure out how to apply the LINQ expression where indicated in the if. Ideas?

Comment: What is `_internalLookup`? It doesn't appear in your sample classes... it is always a bad idea to simplify/replace in your code as you often make mistakes. Your point # 2 is unclear to me. Also what "lowest" level means for #3. Why does point #1 say "values(s)" when a `Dictionary` can only have one value per key, which I assume is property name? A comment on`_indexedItems` that said something like `// Key = property name; Value = Lookup<???, Property Values>` would really be helpful.

Comment: @NetMage - I edited for clarity. The basic problem is that I somehow need to transform the incoming expression to remove the properties as those are encapsulated in the `_backingLookup`. So `x.Manufacturer.IndexOf(...)` is really just `x.IndexOf(...)` because the lookup is already locked to all possible values of the `Manufacturer` property

Comment: Your code isn't compilable (`U` undefined in `IFastIndexingCollection`, no `interface` keyword, fields not allowed in interfaces) which makes it difficult to answer your question.

Comment: What is `FastIndexingCollection<Phone>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a common `ExpressionVisitor` named `Replace`, you can transform the test once you have the `MemberExpression` you need to get the property or field name.

```
public static ExpressionExt {
    /// <summary>
    /// Replaces an Expression (reference Equals) with another Expression
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="orig">The original Expression.</param>
    /// <param name="from">The from Expression.</param>
    /// <param name="to">The to Expression.</param>
    /// <returns>Expression with all occurrences of from replaced with to</returns>
    public static Expression Replace(this Expression orig, Expression from, Expression to) => new ReplaceVisitor(from, to).Visit(orig);
}

/// <summary>
/// ExpressionVisitor to replace an Expression (that is Equals) with another Expression.
/// </summary>
public class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
    readonly Expression from;
    readonly Expression to;

    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node) => node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
}
```

Here is the beginnings of a `FindWhere` implementation that demonstrates using `Replace`:

```
public override IEnumerable<T> FindWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> testFn) {
    var testBody = (BinaryExpression)testFn.Body;
    var fldTestExpr = testBody.Left;
    if (fldTestExpr.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call)
        fldTestExpr = ((MethodCallExpression)fldTestExpr).Object;

    if (fldTestExpr is MemberExpression me) {
        var memberName = me.Member.Name;

        var newp = Expression.Parameter(me.Type);
        var newBody = testBody.Replace(me, newp);
        var newLambda = Expression.Lambda(newBody, newp);

        var newTestFn = newLambda.Compile();
        var testans = (bool) newTestFn.DynamicInvoke("this Samsung that");
        // using DynamicInvoke is not terrible efficient, but lacking a static
        // type for the property means the compiler must use object
    }
}
```

You could improve performance using a version of `FindWhere` that splits the member access from the testing:

```
public override IEnumerable<T> FindWhere2<U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> accessExpr, Func<U, bool> testFn);

var ans = fic.FindWhere2(x => x.Manufacturer, y => y.IndexOf("Samsung") > -1);
```

Comment: Thanks! This gives me enough to get me going. The ExpressionVisitor w/Replace extension is what I needed.